# assigning random values from List<A> into List<B> C#

Tags: c#, linq, random

I'm working on a code that assigns a random numbers from List A into a group of objects in List B.

Here is the requirements:

I have a List of Campaigns and List of CampaignRecipients, and I need to cover three scenarios:

1. When I have equal count on both lists, 2 campaigns and 2 recipients "I have no issue with it at all, it randomly picks a campaignID and assigns it to a randomly picked recipient from List B and so on.
2. When I have 3 campaigns and 1000 recipients, so it will divide the List of recipients into three groups and assigns each group a randomly picked campaign ID.
3. When having 5 campaigns and 3 recipients, then it will randomly pick 3 campaigns and assigns them to the recipients.

The problem I'm having is with point 2.  It takes a very long time, to the point that the operations start timing out.  It distributes the numbers as I want, but it is very slow when dealing with 1k recipients or more.

```
private static void RandomizeScenarios(ref IList<CampaignLib> cmp, ref IList<CampaignRecipientLib> rec)
{
    IEnumerable<int> RecipientsIds = rec.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
    IList<int> CampaignsIds = cmp.Select(x => x.CampaignId.Value).ToList();
    int initVal = RecipientsIds.Count() / CampaignsIds.Count;
    int i = 0;

    if (CampaignsIds.Count < rec.Count())
    {
        List<CampaignRecipientLib> tmpRecipients = new List<CampaignRecipientLib>();

        foreach (var item in CampaignsIds)
        {
            i++;
            IEnumerable<int> tmp = null;

            if (i < CampaignsIds.Count) tmp = RecipientsIds.Shuffle().Take(initVal);
            else tmp = RecipientsIds.Shuffle().Take(RecipientsIds.Count());


            RecipientsIds = from r in RecipientsIds where !tmp.Contains(r) select r;

            var PartialRecipients = from r in rec where tmp.Contains(r.ID) select r;


            // HERE IT TAKES A VERY LONG TIME < 35mins for 2.5K objects
            PartialRecipients.ToList().ForEach(r => r.CampaignId = item);

            tmpRecipients.AddRange(PartialRecipients);

        }
        rec = tmpRecipients;
    }
    else if (CampaignsIds.Count == rec.Count())
    {
        foreach (var item in CampaignsIds)
        {
            int tmp = RecipientsIds.Shuffle().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

            RecipientsIds = from r in RecipientsIds where tmp != r select r;

            rec.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == tmp).CampaignId = item;                  
        }
    }
    else if (CampaignsIds.Count > rec.Count())
    {
        foreach (var item in CampaignsIds.PickRandom(RecipientsIds.Count()).OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            int tmp = RecipientsIds.Shuffle().PickRandom(1).FirstOrDefault();

            RecipientsIds = from r in RecipientsIds where tmp != r select r;

            rec.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(tmp)).CampaignId = item;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Servy as i mentioned in my post, point 2 takes a very long time and sometimes it timeouts

Comment: You shouldn't use quotes to ask your question.  You should use quotes to actually quote things.

Comment: @Servy okay noted, I'm new to stackoverflow, let's focus on the question if there is any useful suggestion, thanks in advance

Comment: What is your implementation of Shuffle? Is it lazy evaluated, if so you might find that you are shuffling every time you do `tmp.Contains`. If so a ToList (or even better stick it in a HashSet) migth solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it too complicated. You can do this:

- Shuffle the list of recipients.
- The first (nr of recipients/campaigncount) recipients get the first campaign
- The next batch of recipients get the second campaign
- Etcetera

This way you only have to shuffle your list once. And you don't have to keep track of which users already had a campaign.

---

Example:

- Users: 1 2 3 4 5 6
- Campaigns: 1 2

Shuffle your users:

- Users: (5 3 2 4 1 6)
- Users (5 3 2) get campaign 1
- Users (4 1 6) get campaign 2

Comment: The problem is by assigning a campaign ID to N objects of Recipients - it is super slow. is there a way to do it in one line instead of using ForEach?

Comment: Also, shuffle the list of campaigns, to ensure that not just the first few campaigns are sent when campaigns>recipients.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion, but my problem is still with assigning a picked campaign id to a group of 5k recipients, my approach is super slow, any fast way to do it?

Comment: @B.Simboliq: are you sure its the assigning that is slow and not the `PartialRecipients.ToList()`?

Comment: @Chris no the ForEach I tested the code and ran another sample using ForEach only and it is still slow

Comment: Split your code in two: the PartialRecipients.ToList() and the Foreach and you'll see it's the tolist that's slow.

Comment: @B.Simboliq: so if you do `var tempList = PartialRecipients.ToList(); tempList.ForEach(r => r.CampaignId = item);` it executes the first statement very qucikly and the second take 35 minutes? I find this incredibly hard to believe since a loop like that with just a single assignment in it *really* shouldn't take almost a second per iteration. The only explanation that makes sense is that you are doing far more work on each iteration than you realise.

Comment: Does he even need that partial recipients or reassigning rec back and forth and all? Just generate a simple pair<int,int> list with recID:campID and iterate over rec setting related field.